# Performance profiling and tuning in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Beyond the immediate suspects defined in the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-tuning), what are some ways to profile, tune and boost performance of an Apache Spark application?

Comment: This question seems very broad.  What are the "immediate suspects" and why aren't they adequate for your needs?

Comment: My main issue is that I don't know if I'm over caching or under caching. I would like to know if there is a tool that does spark profiling. I think I covered the usual suspects, but still think it's too slow. My question is beyond the usual suspects, just like a standalone JVM has JProfiler etc, what is the equivalent profiling tool for a distributed system such as Spark?

Comment: I think this is better on Stack Overflow, but it's too old to migrate